# Why the null values become 0 in my Room entity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

In my SQLite database I have this table defined:

```
CREATE TABLE `lh_psalm_join` (
    `groupFK` INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    `readingFK` INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    `theOrder` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `themeFK` INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    `epigraphFK` INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    `thePart` INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`groupFK`, `readingFK`),
    FOREIGN KEY(`groupFK`) REFERENCES `lh_psalmody_join`(`groupID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(`readingFK`) REFERENCES `lh_psalm`(`psalmID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(`epigraphFK`) REFERENCES `lh_epigraph`(`epigraphID`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(`themeFK`) REFERENCES `lh_theme`(`themeID`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
  );
```

My question is regarding the `theOrder` column, in the entity I have it defined like this:

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "thePart", defaultValue = "NULL")
var thePart: Int?
```

Retrieving the data, when the value of `theParte` is `null` in the database, it becomes `0`.

I realized this because when I tried to do this check it told me that it would always be true:

```
if (thePart != null || thePart !=0)
```

In Room are **`null`** values converted to **`0`**? Is `if (myVaule != 0)` enough for this case?

I was looking through the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/ColumnInfo) and couldn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Room isn't converting null to 0. Your analysis of your own conditional

```
thePart != null || thePart != 0
```

is incorrect.

Consider three possible categories of the value of `thePart`:

| Value of `thePart` | Result |
| --- | --- |
| null | `thePart != 0` will be true |
| 0 | `thePart != null` will be true |
| Any integer besides 0 | `thePart != null` will be true |

So one of your two criteria is true no matter what, and you use `||` for the two criteria, so it must always be true.

Comment: Ok, I see. The correct way would then be to use `&&`?

Comment: I don’t know because I don’t know what you’re trying to do with that condition.

Comment: I want to check if `thePart` is not null and not equal to `0`.

Comment: Then yes, `&&` is the operator for “and”.

Answer (score 1):

In short Room does not convert null to 0, your logic, as per the warning issues, will always result in true.

- *in fact if anything the reverse is true when using Kotlin, if an integer type that is not nullable and is the primary key (solely) then if the value is 0, Room will affectively treat the value as if null and not provide a value in the insert so that a value is generated*

**Explanation**

> I realized this because when I tried to do this check it told me that it would always be true:  `if (thePart != null || thePart !=0)`

Lets say thePart is null

Is thePart not equal to null = false (condition not met) OR Is thePart not equal to 0 = true (condition met), as such the Or'd together is true.

In the case where thePart is 10 (or anything but 0) then because 10 is not null, you get a true so true.

In the case where thePart is 0 then again 0 is not null so true.

As such you will always get true, nothing at all to do with Room.

**Introducing What Room Does**

Ignoring the Foreign Keys (as these require the referenced tables to exist), then your @Entity class would be along the lines of:-

```
@Entity(tableName = "lh_psalm_join", primaryKeys = ["groupFK","readingFK"])
data class LH_PSALM(
    var groupFK: Int,
    var readingFK: Int,
    var theOrder: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "NULL")
    var themeFK: Int?=null,
    @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "NULL")
    var epigraph: Int?=null,
    @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "NULL")
    var thePart: Int?=null
    /* Foreign keys omitted */
)
```

Also an @Dao annotated interface to allow data to be inserted and extracted

```
@Dao
interface TheDAOS{
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(lhPsalm: LH_PSALM): Long
    @Query("SELECT * FROM lh_psalm_join")
    fun getAllLHPSALMs(): List<LH_PSALM>
}
```

- i.e. no special handling at all.

Which generates the create SQL:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lh_psalm_join` (
    `groupFK` INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    `readingFK` INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    `theOrder` INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    `themeFK` INTEGER DEFAULT NULL, 
    `epigraph` INTEGER DEFAULT NULL, 
    `thePart` INTEGER DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(`groupFK`, `readingFK`)
)
```

i.e. bar the Foreign Keys the same SQL as provided in the question.

- Foreign Keys for nullable fields will very likely result in issues and angst, but that is out of scope of the question asked. Their inclusion would cloud the issue.

Now consider the following activity code (note that the  `.allowMainThreadQueries` method has been included in the Room databaseBuilder, for brevity and convenience):-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TaskRoomDatabase
    lateinit var dao: TheDAOS
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TaskRoomDatabase.getDatabase(this)
        dao = db.getTheDAOs()

        var lp = LH_PSALM( groupFK = 1, readingFK = 1, 99, null, null, null)
        dao.insert(lp)
        dao.insert(LH_PSALM(2,2,98,1,null,null))
        dao.insert(LH_PSALM(3,3,97))
        dao.insert(LH_PSALM(4,4,96,0,0,0))

        for(lp in dao.getAllLHPSALMs()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","GFK=${lp.groupFK} RFK=${lp.readingFK} ORD=${lp.theOrder} THM=${lp.themeFK} EP=${lp.epigraph} PRT=${lp.thePart}" +
                    " The logical processing of the thePart field:-" +
                    "\n\t Is thePart NOT EQUAL TO NULL?: ${lp.thePart!=null}" +
                    " Is thePart NOT EQUAL to 0?: ${lp.thePart!=0}" +
                    " Is thePart NOW EQUAL TO NULL OR NOT EQUAL TO 0 ${(lp.thePart!=null || lp.thePart!=0)}"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The first run (the above is only intended to be run the once) results in the log including:-

```
D/DBINFO: GFK=1 RFK=1 ORD=99 THM=null EP=null PRT=null The logical processing of the thePart field:-
         Is thePart NOT EQUAL TO NULL?: false Is thePart NOT EQUAL to 0?: true Is thePart NOW EQUAL TO NULL OR NOT EQUAL TO 0 true
D/DBINFO: GFK=2 RFK=2 ORD=98 THM=1 EP=null PRT=null The logical processing of the thePart field:-
         Is thePart NOT EQUAL TO NULL?: false Is thePart NOT EQUAL to 0?: true Is thePart NOW EQUAL TO NULL OR NOT EQUAL TO 0 true
D/DBINFO: GFK=3 RFK=3 ORD=97 THM=null EP=null PRT=null The logical processing of the thePart field:-
         Is thePart NOT EQUAL TO NULL?: false Is thePart NOT EQUAL to 0?: true Is thePart NOW EQUAL TO NULL OR NOT EQUAL TO 0 true
D/DBINFO: GFK=4 RFK=4 ORD=96 THM=0 EP=0 PRT=0 The logical processing of the thePart field:-
         Is thePart NOT EQUAL TO NULL?: true Is thePart NOT EQUAL to 0?: false Is thePart NOW EQUAL TO NULL OR NOT EQUAL TO 0 true
```

1. clearly Room has not replaced null with 0 not vice-versa e.g. `THM=null EP=null PRT=null`
2. The logic results clearly show that even if parts are false, that ORing the two test, returns false.

To further demonstrate that nulls are stored in the database App Inspection (after running the above) shows:-

[image]

Comment: You are right. I was doing the conversion elsewhere in the code and hadn't realized it: `get() = if (psalmodyEntity.thePart!=null) psalmodyEntity.thePart else 0`

Answer (score -1):

Default Values: When you define a property in your Room entity class, if you don't specify a default value, it will be set to the default value for its data type. For example, if you have an integer field and it's not explicitly set to a value, it will default to 0.

> ```
> @Entity
> public class MyEntity {
>     @PrimaryKey
>     public int id;
>
>     public int myIntegerField; // Defaults to 0 if not explicitly set
> }
> ```

**For null value**

> ```
> @Entity
> public class MyEntity {
>     @PrimaryKey
>     public int id;
>
>     @Nullable
>     public Integer myNullableIntegerField; // Allows null values
> }
> ```